# Pulling in the next value in a column

Tags: excel

I have a column with numbers and a column with country locations.  I want the formula to go down the country location column and produce any number that is associated with "USA."  I can get the first value, but because "USA" isn't a unique value within the column I'm referencing, it always and only produces the first number.  How do I get it to continue pulling the next number down the row? In the below example, I want the first result to be 56436, the next to be 50131, and so on.  What is the formula that needs to be written so that it continues down the column?

```
Number      Country
00080462    Portugal
00080132    Portugal
00080183    Portugal
00080187    Portugal
00056436    USA
00092002    United Kingdom
00050131    USA
00056556    USA
00057100    USA
00057938    USA
00051993    USA
00055780    USA
00091879    United Kingdom
00052248    USA
00056019    USA
00091944    United Kingdom
00025547    USA
00091977    United Kingdom
```

Comment: Why not just use a filter?

Comment: Thanks Ron, and normally I would.  However, I'm creating a template off of a dump sheet. So I want the template to automatically read the dump sheet and pull in for the respective country. I will be trying all solutions suggested in these threads.

Answer (score 2):

try this at the top of an unused column and fill down,

```
=index(a:a, aggregate(15, 7, row($2:$20)/(b$2:b$20="usa"), row(1:1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sample data+header is in A1:B17 type this in D2, then drag downwards.  :

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROWS($A$2:$A2)>1,INDEX(OFFSET($A$2:$A$19,MATCH(D1,$A$2:$A$19,0),0),MATCH("USA",OFFSET($B$2:$B$19,MATCH(D1,$A$2:$A$19,0),0),0)),INDEX($A$2:$A$19,MATCH("USA",$B$2:$B$19,0))),"")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hurm.. I didn't.. here's my [testbench](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EcaJs9fuIWdPoWvQa_M0N04B5ae2LFTHsK3pMnE6KqIKNw?e=2fDmwb) sample file.

Comment: I believe it has to do with `MATCH(D1, ....` I just put your formula any old place.

Comment: I use the D1 to "start" the non-1st-match evaluation.. if the data above = empty > give 1st USA match, else if data above results in "USA" match, the evaluation for 'the-next-nth-match' started.

Comment: @Jeeped good note there.. for your case.. try replacing `D1` in the formula to `OFFSET(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address"),"$","")),-1,0)` || I intend to leave it as `D1` for the OP to work out the `index() + match()` [internal workings](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) by him/herself, that's why I state my assumptions.. IMHO.. it's a very thought comment, Thanks. /(^_^)

Comment: Generally speaking, an OP will just copy and paste what is offered into their own situation without reading the accompanying narrative. I've found that 'spoon feeding' a solution leads to less *'it doesn't work'* response comments. JMHO, and certainly not obligatory in all cases. I'd up-vote but I've already done that.